# Born with a weight of 5kg

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, register

Which of these would it make sense for me to say?

1. My baby was born with a weight of 5kg
2. My baby was born at 5kg
3. My baby was born weighing 5kg

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you *could* say all of them, but #2 could have a totally different meaning if you switch 5kg with a place (my baby was born at the mall). #1 and #3 are relatively equal, but in my opinion #3 sounds the most normal out of all of them.

Comment: my friend said her baby was born by 5kg.. is it grammartically wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, *by* is the wrong preposition there. Worse, there isn't a right preposition to put there. The sentence would need to be recast.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **born weighing** is much more likely than the other two phrases to come out of the mouth of a native speaker when referring to their own child in normal conversation.

**born at a weight** and **born with a weight** are clinical in tone, not conversational. These phrases are more likely to be found in a  medical article.

Comment: my friend said her baby was born by 5kg.. is it grammartically wrong?

Comment: My wife, a retired midwife, consistently uses the form "The baby's birth weight was 5kg". You could also say "The baby weighed 5kg at birth", "The baby weighed 5kg when born" or "The baby weighed 5kg when he was born", which last is more conversational, and gives a little more information -- the gender of the child!  "Born by 5kg" is definitely wrong!